# add simple line chart in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c

am new for charts in ios developing apps..

am having two array values like

```
    ProgramenameArray
    BudgetCostArray
```

i want to draw a simple line chat using those arrays use as x-axis and Y-axis respectively...

i tried like this..

```
   - (void)loadChartWithDates
         {

       NSMutableArray* chartData = [NSMutableArray      arr   ayWithCapacity:programNmaeIdArray.count];
NSLog(@"the array ^^^^^ values are %@ %@ ",programNmaeIdArray,programNameArray);
for(int i=0;i<programIdArray.count;i++)
{
    chartData[i] = programIdArray[i];
}

     NSMutableArray *months = [[NSArray alloc]init];
months=projectNameArray;

  // Setting up the line chart
 // _chartWithDates.verticalGridStep = 6;
//_chartWithDates.horizontalGridStep = 3;
  _chartWithDates.fillColor = nil;
  _chartWithDates.displayDataPoint = YES;
  _chartWithDates.dataPointColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  _chartWithDates.dataPointBackgroundColor = [UIColor fsDarkBlue];
  _chartWithDates.dataPointRadius = 2;
  _chartWithDates.color = [_chartWithDates.dataPointColor     colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
_chartWithDates.valueLabelPosition = ValueLabelLeftMirrored;

  _chartWithDates.labelForIndex = ^(NSUInteger item)
  {
    return months[item];
  };

_chartWithDates.labelForValue = ^(CGFloat value)
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f €", value];
};

  [_chartWithDates setChartData:chartData];
```

}

so can anyone help...Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: refer this https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart

Comment: you can go for core plot library or javascript.